# No signature of method: *** is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: getRandomShippingMethod()

Tags: groovy

I want to write a script on the groovy script, but i have this exception:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ru.evgeny.in.order.bob.util.dbutil.DBStandaloneFullXMLUtil.randomShippingMethod() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getRandomShippingMethod()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ru.evgeny.in.order.bob.util.dbutil.DBStandaloneFullXMLUtil.randomShippingMethod() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getRandomShippingMethod()
    at Draft.run(Draft.groovy:6)
```

my groovy script:

```
    import ru.evgeny.in.order.bob.util.dbutil.DBStandaloneFullXMLUtil

    def db = new DBStandaloneFullXMLUtil()

    println db.getRandomSKU()
    println db.randomShippingMethod()
```

DBStandaloneFullXMLUtil:

```
class DBStandaloneFullXMLUtil implements IDBUtil {
....
    @Override
    def getRandomSKU() {
        def rows = 'id, item_nr'
        def table = '(select * from mywms_itemdata where dtype = \'LMItemData\') as LMItemData'
        getRandomeRow(rows, table).values()
    }

    @Override
    def getRandomShippingMethod(){
        def rows = 'id, name'
        def table = 'lm_shipping_method'
        getRandomeRow(rows, table).values()
    }
}
```

Why i get this exception??? Why there is no exception on

```
println db.getRandomSKU()
```

Comment: Double check the following line - `println db.randomShippingMethod()`. It seems like you made a typo and you call `randomShippingMethod` instead of `getRandomShippingMethod`. The exception you get says exactly that.

Comment: Or to be more clear: it's either `db.randomShippingMethod` or `db.getRandomShippingMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two accessor methods in your class: `getRandomSKU` and `getRandomShippingMethod`, but you call them in two different ways:

```
println db.getRandomSKU()
println db.randomShippingMethod()
```

You should change the above to either:

```
println db.randomSKU
println db.randomShippingMethod
```

(which indirectly calls your accessor methods), or you could use:

```
println db.getRandomSKU()
println db.getRandomShippingMethod()
```

(which directly calls those methods)